# Start a program in Windows as it is run in a clean system

Tags: windows, environment-variables

Is it a way to start a program in Windows as it is run in a clean system (without any software or libraries installed)?

I can do something like `set PATH=` but it is not sufficient as I can see. E.g. *Microsoft Visual Studio Redistributable Packages* don't use `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: What exactly is your intension? To what purpose do you need that?

Comment: @duDE I want to test my application on a clean system and don't want to use virtual machines for this purpose.

Comment: But in this case the using of a clean windows installation on a VM would be really the best choice for you, don't it? You can even make a Snapshot after installing and so have allways the clean environment ...

Comment: @duDE OK, thank you. I only wanted to know whether a bit simpler solution exists. Now I see that use of VMs in this situation is a choice with no alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

My best advice would be to use a virtual machine. There are free virtualization softwares like Virtual Box that you could use. The only drawback is that you would need a Windows install media (I recommend an ISO file). You don't need an activation key if you just plan to use the VM in a temporary manner.

**EDIT**: As the other answerers pointed out, you will obviously need at leats your program and all its prerequisites (usually, .NET Framework, Visual C++ or DirectX for 3D apps) which are not by default on a Windows clean install.

If you *do not* want to use a VM, you will need to uninstall everything you installed until now. If you develop software that needs to be tested in a clean environment, I *really* ***really*** suggest you start using VMs as your testing environment.

Comment: IMHO as well! a very best choice  +1

Answer (score 0):

I think it will only be possible if you program contains the required libraries or other files, otherwise you won't.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is generally speaking definitely NOT possible!

In your example (Visual Studio) you have a Tool that uses many [COM components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model).
This is only possible by registration of components by Windows Registry, this is only the way this DLLs can be found.

But in your concept of "clean system" the using of Windows Registry will be not allowed!